# The Tanakh books and the number 24 - what preceded what?

Tags: number, tanach

The Talmud evidently describes the existence of numerous extra-Biblical works (Apocrypha?).

When the sages decided on the canon ([Bava_Batra.14b?)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.15a.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), was it decided on each book separately and the number came occasionally to 24, or the number 24 was chosen apriori and the Holy books were fit into it one on the expense of another?

Comment: why would the latter possibility even be a hava amina?

Comment: @wfb Because if the nimber preceded the content, that would be an external reason having no connection with a book's holiness.

Comment: @wfb's point is that there is absolutely no reason to think the latter is true.

Comment: @N.T. You can't claim toward another person "there's no reason of thinking what you think". I have lots of reasons that seem very intelligible, for example - why Torah's 5 books and not 1. Why all minor prophets aren't a single book? Why other books are excluded? And many more.

Comment: @AlBerko if you don't motivate your question, that's the response you should expect. There is no reason in the question to think your suggestion is worth thinking about and no reason has appeared as obvious to any of us.

Comment: @DoubleAA I like your royal us. L'Judaisme c'ete moi.

Comment: @AlBerko Not royal us. Us is me, N.T., wfb and 6 voters on his comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sid Z. Leiman, The Canonization of Hebrew Scripture, p. 56:

> A biblical canon of precisely twenty-four books is nowhere mentioned in early talmudic or midrashic materials such as the Mekhilta, Sifre, Tosefta and Mishnah. Though it is certain that all twenty-four books were known in the early tannaitic period, it is possible that another system of counting the biblical books was in use (such as the twenty-two book count of Josephus...). It seems likely, however, that the twenty-four book count was already known and in use during the tannaitic period. Its oldest attestation appears in the Fourth Book of Ezra, whose final redaction is dated to ca. 100 C.E. Some Tannaim and Amoraim, however, rejected the twenty-four book count and adopted a more limited biblical canon. They relegated several of the biblical books to uninspired canonical status...

Comment: Thank you. Very informative.

Answer (score 1):

The Midrash Tanchuma (Buber Parshat Ki Tisa) states:

> אמר רב הונא אמר ריש לקיש מה הכלה הזאת מתקשטת בעשרים וארבעה תכשיטין כך תלמיד חכם צריך להיות זריז בכ"ד ספרים
>
> Said R. Huna in the name of Reish Lakish: Just as this bride is adorned with 24 adornments, so must a scholar be adroit in the 24 books [of Scripture].

This comparison would only work if there were precisely 24 books, so this could potentially be taken as an indication that the number 24 may have preceded the books.

Comment: A nice point. So after the tradition of 24 adornments, they limited the books of Tanach? Interesting! Any Ideas what they are? Something Babylonian style?

Comment: This sounds more like a backronym of sorts (our whatever the equivalent is for numbers), where we have the number 24 and are sharing teachings learnt out from that, not that we have a teaching and therefore make the number of books 24. Reish Lakish was long after the sealing of the Tanach, after all.